# What is the function of a commented out function and "comma splice"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comments

I've been dissecting a few bits of code over the past two weeks and I keep seeing some reoccurring themes... For example, what is the point of the following...?

```
class eventHandler(object):
    def create_event(self, event):
        """A general note here.

        :tagged param event:
            description
        :tagged type event:
            :class: `another class` # I do not understand the comma splices ( ` ).
        """
        # I do not understand why it ends here with no real purpose. Perhaps I'm not catching on to something.

    def next_event(self, event):
        ...
        # Continues with the same logic from above
```

I have seen it in the Python Module "watchdog" as well as other modules and code snippets from the past that are scattered around on the internet. Is this just a sudo-code format for keeping notes? Were the functions discontinued? Am I just not understanding something in particular?

Edit:

Artagel brought up a good reference, I hadn't read deep enough [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: It's standard PEP8 formatting.  PyCharm pro will actually do a lot of this for you.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @Artagel I must've missed seeing that. Thank you for the documentation (I'll be tossing it up in my question to help others out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backquotes probably have meaning to some sort of documentation generator that parses doc strings to produce nicely formatted documentation. They have no meaning in the Python language itself.

`create_event` is probably a method intended to be implemented by a subclass of `eventHandler`. The doc string alone is sufficient, syntactically, to serve as the body of the method. Without the doc string, you would need to use the `pass` statement to serve as a placeholder for a "real" body.

```
def create_event(self, event):
    pass
```

Comment: Ah, ok, so that completely answers my question! Thank you so much, Chepner! I've got another question, but I hesitate to ask it here, as it should probably thrown into another thread...

Comment: I'll ask it here... What is a good reason for having a the event passed in such a function? Debugging?

Comment: The only thing I can think of without knowing the intended semantics of the class is to allow making a copy of an existing event (or a new event similar to an existing event).

Comment: Good enough for me! A few of them are just there, others are definitely copies of existing events that are just blank, but the working ones are listed under another class. It appears they work together, to some extent.